# Prevent browser from vertical scrolling after clicking <a href="#divID">

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

In the middle of my page I got a tiny menu, when you click a button it will horizontally scroll to the content you've chosen. But when you click it the entire window scrolls so the menu is on the top. Here's the graphical representation of my issue.

http://imgur.com/yJe7wg8

Here's the code I'm going to modify and use:

```
<div id="left">
<a href="#target1" class="panel">Target 1</a><br/>
<a href="#target2" class="panel">Target 2</a><br/>
<a href="#target3" class="panel">Target 3</a><br/>
```

```
<div id="right">
<div class="panel" id="target1" style="background:green">Target 1</div>
<div class="panel" id="target2" style="background:red">Target 2</div>
<div class="panel" id="target3" style="background:yellow">Target 3</div>
```

+some jQuery to make it slide from #left to #right

Here's the working demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/codeSpy/KyV6L/

Comment: So what exactly is your requirement

Comment: Why don't you just get rid of the href if you don't actually want it to behave like a link?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default action of a `#` link is to navigate the the named `ID`. You need to prevent the default action:

```
$('a.panel').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    /* rest of your function ... */
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that did  the trick. But now "    $("#target1").addClass('active').show();" doesn't work on my website (in fiddle it works). Instead of activating "#target1" it remains blank until I click target2 or target3 (clicking target1 doesn't do anything). Do you have any idea why is that?

Answer (score 1):

Use a `return false` or a `preventDefault()` in your click event:

```
$('a.panel').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // ...
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to prevent the default action of the click event using `preventDefault()`:

```
$('a.panel').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    ...
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This helped me prevent vertical scrolling while allowing horizontal scrolling.

```
$('a').click(function(e) {
var aid = $(this).attr("href");
$('html,body').animate({scrollTop: 0});});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem you're having might be coming from the hrefs you're using. As they're actual urls, they try to navigate (scroll) to the anchors that you define with the #'s. Cause they don't exist, the page will automaticly scroll to the top of your site.

Try using ID's as attributes instead, or as the other answers suggested prevent the default action.