# How to prevent js scroll to top on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

I'm having trouble with what I believe to be a javascript or jQuery issue.
I have build a css checkbox label that when clicked reveals a form on the page.

The problem I'm having is that when the label is clicked, if the user has scrolled down before clicking, the page scrolls to top.

I believe this is a JS issue, maybe coming from the theme I am using, but my JS skills are close to none so I would really appreciate any help.

You can view the page here:
http://urlgone.com/5504c5/

and the "Scroll to top" happens when clicking on the "sign up" blue text.

I've tried adding this JS code as suggested in [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20220239/prevent-browser-from-vertical-scrolling-after-clicking-a-href-divid), but that didn't solve the issue.

```
$("#slidingFormBtnId").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // Do your stuff
});
```

Comment: Check your console ~ *"Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function"*

Comment: @Phil that's because JQuery isn't included, it's not an issue with the code

Comment: @Markasoftware you don't think that might prevent OP's code from working?

Comment: well, his real code probably has JQuery included, so yeah, I don't think this would be causing any issues

Comment: @Markasoftware I'm looking at his site, jQuery is there but for some reason I haven't seen yet, `$` is not defined. OP should just use `jQuery('#slideingFormBtnId').click(...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your issue in that you are attempting to use jquery incorrectly inside Wordpress. Your console states `$ is not a function`.

You can view this page for some help: https://digwp.com/2011/09/using-instead-of-jquery-in-wordpress/ but basically you should wrap your jquery in:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {
 // code here
}
```

Comment: Thanks!    

After finally succeding to add the code I had another problem- the checkbox wasn't being toggled any more because of the `.preventDefault()` so I needed to add another line of code to solve this matter.    

Now works great and code looks like this:    


 `jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {

 $("#slidingFormBtnId").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('#toggleForm').trigger('click'); 
 });
}); `